# Change date format with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, date

I have a data frame with a column 'object type' called 'Fecha' and I would like to cast it as DateTime type.
However, pandas cannot recognize the format as it is some kind of Spanish format (i.e: '1 abr, 2019'). What should I do to change to a standard format like dd/mm/yyyy?

Abr corresponds to Abril which is April in English.

[image: Fecha column]

I have tried with pd.to_datetime() and strftime method but pandas cannot recognize the format.

```
ValueError: ('Unknown string format:', '1 abr. 2019')
```

Greetings and thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try locale? 
` import locale `
`locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL,'es_ES.UTF-8')`
`from datetime import datetime as dt`
`print(dt.strptime('martes 12 julio 2016', '%A %d %B %Y'))`

Comment: Please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors. Where is the [mcve]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set the locale to `es_ES` you can convert the string series to datetime using `pd.to_datetime` and the appropriate format codes from [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).

In this case the format code is `%d %b %Y` (well, not exactly since the days are not zero padded, but `pd.to_datetime` doesn't seem to care).

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, locale='es_ES')

df['Fecha'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Fecha'], format='%d %b %Y')
```

Comment: Seems it is working out for some rows but not all rows.

`ValueError: time data '3 sept. 2019' does not match format '%d %b %Y' (match)`

Comment: The Spanish locales that abbreviate September as 'sept.' are: `es-CL`, `es-CO`, `es-PY` and `es-VE`. Replace the locale code with any of those and it should work.